# MySQL - Select multiple rows with the same values with one having to be different

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table for IP addresses used and the associated userId. Now I know how I would select multiple entries of the same IP but how would I go about only selecting multiple entries WITH a different userId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation over each ip address and check to see if more than one user be associated with that ip address.

```
SELECT ip
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) > 1    -- or a higher number if you want
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use sql join do it for you 
**INNER JOIN** gets all records from one table that have some related entry in a second table

**LEFT JOIN** gets all records from the LEFT linked table but if you have selected some columns from the RIGHT table, if there is no related records, these columns will contain NULL

**RIGHT JOIN** is like the above but gets all records in the RIGHT table

**FULL JOIN** gets all records from both tables and puts NULL in the columns where related records do not exist in the opposite table

[SQL joins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJDxk.png)